# Doctrine Documentation for 1.2

Tags: orm, documentation, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

Anyone happen to know what happened to the Doctrine docs for 1.x? Going through their [official documentation page](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html) (have to scrolldown to 1.2), and clicking any of the documentation links results in a 404. I have also noticed that several google searches for 1.x docs are doing the same.

Did Doctrine recently change doc structure and forget to update? Or is this their way of telling us to upgrade to 2.x?

**-- Update (3.9.2012) --**

It appears that Doctrine was in the middle of moving their documentation to GitHub. Some of the links mentioned in OP are now resolving to [https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine1-documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html).

**-- Update (3.20.2012) --**

Looks like some of the documentation has been ported over to their [ReadTheDocs](https://doctrine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) portal. Much cleaner interface than browsing the raw .txt files.

Comment: So will there be an official Doctrine 1.2.4 ( for example ) documentation page as before?

Comment: Not sure... right now I have to go to the github link posted above and parse through the .txt files.

Comment: It looks like doctrine 1.2 documentation is again vanished from ReadTheDocs, any idea what happened to documentation ?

Comment: Here is a shortcut to Doctrine 1.2.4 http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [thread](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine1-documentation/issues/2) on github, the powers that be are aware of the problem and should be fixing it soon. Someone posted a link to a [cached version](http://goo.gl/P6ZRo) of the docs, which works well in the interim.

Answer (score 1):

The current situation is that I'm porting the docs over to reStructuredText on a fork of the official doctrine1-documentation. This is the version you can see over at [ReadTheDocs](http://readthedocs.org/docs/doctrine/en/latest/en/manual/index.html).

The idea is to eventually end up with a reST version of the entire manual, at which point the documentation can be PR'd back into the official repo, built by the same system that builds Doctrine2's documentation, and end up back on the official Doctrine site.

In the meantime, some chapters are nice and easy to read, like [Defining Models](http://readthedocs.org/docs/doctrine/en/latest/en/manual/defining-models.html), while others have [yet to receive fixed markup](http://readthedocs.org/docs/doctrine/en/latest/en/manual/coding-standards.html). Help with fixing it all up is welcome ([fork](http://github.com/dominics/doctrine1-documentation)).

Comment: Ya I noticed the port over to ReadTheDocs a few days ago, it does look nice. Sucks all those links from google are broken though. Seems like a better way to handle it would be to add perm redirects to the new stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Doctrine 1.2.4 Documentation
http://doctrinedocs.com

Comment: Welcome on SO Kevin. Thanks for sharing your new website but it's not an answer to the question. Your link provide only an api documentation generated by Doxygen. OP is looking for the **real documentation** of Doctrine.

Comment: I've been on SO for a while. My OpenID registrar went under and I have no way to recover my original account.

What you call the real documentation is actually a manual. API Documentation for Doctrine is very hard to find which is why I created the site cause I'm tired of searching for "doctrine docs Doctrine_Manager" and google coming back with either this page or the manual.

Comment: After less than 24 hours, this new site is already the #1 result on google for the search term "doctrine docs [classname]"